# Deserialize wrapped list using Jackson

Tags: java, json, list, jackson

I have a JSON Object like this:

```
{"geonames":[
   {"countryId":"2017370",
    "adminCode1":"73"},
   {"countryId":"2027370",
    "adminCode1":"71"},
    ...]}
```

How can i deserialize this object **DIRECTLY** to `List<GeoName>`, ignoring the first layer (geonames wrapper), instead of deserializing to a wrapper object containing `List<GeoName>` as `@JsonProperty("geonames")`?

Comment: if you are getting this JSON from any rest endpoint then try spring rest template, it has messgae converters which will take care of marshalling and unmarshalling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an `ObjectReader` with a root name

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectReader reader = mapper.reader(new TypeReference<List<GeoName>>() {}).withRootName("geonames");
List<GeoName> list = reader.readValue(json);
```

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this with annnotations? Without instantiating a reader?

Comment: @localhost Not while deserializing to `List<GeoName>` directly. If you could change the root name to `List`, you could use `mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);` and use the mapper directly.

Comment: @localhost But what's wrong with `ObjectReader`? These are generated internally anyway.

Comment: can't change the root name. Thx for answer, i accept it :)