# Jackson - deserialize inner list of objects to list of one higher level

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

With Spring Boot and Jackson, how can I deserialize a wrapped/inner list into a list directly in the outer level?

For example, I have:

```
{
    "transaction": {
    "items": {
        "item": [
            {
                "itemNumber": "193487654",
                "itemDescription": "Widget",
                "itemPrice": "599.00",
                "itemQuantity": "1",
                "itemBrandName": "ACME",
                "itemCategory": "Electronics",
                "itemTax": "12.95"
            },
            {
                "itemNumber": "193487654",
                "itemDescription": "Widget",
                "itemPrice": "599.00",
                "itemQuantity": "1",
                "itemBrandName": "ACME",
                "itemCategory": "Electronics",
                "itemTax": "12.95"
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
    }
}
```

In the JSON, `item` is a list under `items`; but I want to parse it as a list named `items`, directly under `transaction`, instead of defining a DTO `Items` which contains a list named `item`.

Is this possible? How to define this DTO `Item`?

```
public class TrasactionDTO {
    private List<Item> items;
    ...
}

public class Item {

}
```

This question is similar but does not solve the problem.
[Deserialize wrapped list using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27699538/deserialize-wrapped-list-using-jackson)

Comment: Not possible to modify the data structure of the JSON to get it how you want it? Like right before posting the data, do `data.items = data.items.item;` ?

Comment: The JSON is passed in as request body, I am not aware of ways of doing beforehand conversion.

Comment: one way is custom deserializer

Comment: Yes although not so familiar with that. And I have like 4 fields like this; if we can do it with some annotations it could be better?

Comment: @WesternGun The data is coming from what? A form post? You can change the names of the fields. An AJAX request? Put `data.items = data.items.item;` right before you post.

I'm just saying, before you get fancy in Java, follow the problem back a step. Why is the data shaped like this instead of how you want it? What mechanism issues this request in the first place?

Comment: may be try with this `@JsonRootName("items")` on top of `public class TrasactionDTO`https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations

Comment: This comes from a 3rd party provider; its documentation features this example I am using.

Comment: how about @JsonValue which indicates a single method that the library will use to serialize the entire instance.
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `@JsonUnwrapped` is what I need.

https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations

> **@JsonUnwrapped** defines values that should be unwrapped/flattened when serialized/deserialized.
>
> Let's see exactly how that works; we'll use the annotation to unwrap the property name:
>
> ```
> public class UnwrappedUser {
>     public int id;
>  
>     @JsonUnwrapped
>     public Name name;
>  
>     public static class Name {
>         public String firstName;
>         public String lastName;
>     }
>  }
> ```
>
> Let's now serialize an instance of this class:
>
> ```
> @Test
> public void whenSerializingUsingJsonUnwrapped_thenCorrect()
>   throws JsonProcessingException, ParseException {
>     UnwrappedUser.Name name = new UnwrappedUser.Name("John", "Doe");
>     UnwrappedUser user = new UnwrappedUser(1, name);
>  
>     String result = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(user);
>      
>     assertThat(result, containsString("John"));
>     assertThat(result, not(containsString("name")));
> }
> ```
>
> Here's how the output looks like – the fields of the static nested class unwrapped along with the other field:
>
> ```
> {
>     "id":1,
>     "firstName":"John",
>     "lastName":"Doe"
> }
> ```

So, it should be something like:

```java
public class TrasactionDTO {
    
    private List<Item> items;
    ...
}

public static class Item {
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private InnerItem innerItem;
    ...

}

public static class InnerItem {
    private String itemNumber;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

We need to implement custom deserialiser. Because we want to skip one inner field our implementation should:

1. `{` - skip start object
2. `"any_field_name"` - skip any field name. We assume that we have only one inner field.
3. `[{}, ..., {}]` - use default deserialiser for `List`.
4. `}` - skip end object

Using above concept implementation should be easy:

```
public class InnerListDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<List> implements ContextualDeserializer {

    private final JavaType propertyType;

    public InnerListDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public InnerListDeserializer(JavaType propertyType) {
        this.propertyType = propertyType;
    }

    @Override
    public List deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        p.nextToken(); // SKIP START_OBJECT
        p.nextToken(); // SKIP any FIELD_NAME

        List list = context.readValue(p, propertyType);

        p.nextToken(); // SKIP END_OBJECT

        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext context, BeanProperty property) {
        return new InnerListDeserializer(property.getType());
    }
}
```

Let's assume we have `JSON` payload like this:

```
{
  "transaction": {
    "items": {
      "item": [
        {
          "itemNumber": "193487654",
          "itemDescription": "Widget",
          "itemPrice": "599.00",
          "itemQuantity": "1",
          "itemBrandName": "ACME",
          "itemCategory": "Electronics",
          "itemTax": "12.95"
        },
        {
          "itemNumber": "193487654",
          "itemDescription": "Widget",
          "itemPrice": "599.00",
          "itemQuantity": "1",
          "itemBrandName": "ACME",
          "itemCategory": "Electronics",
          "itemTax": "12.95"
        }
      ]
    },
    "name": "Pickle Rick"
  }
}
```

Above `JSON` we can map to below `POJO` classes:

```
@JsonRootName("transaction")
public class Transaction {

    private String name;
    private List<Item> items;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = InnerListDeserializer.class)
    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    // getters, setters, toString
}

public class Item {

    private String itemNumber;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

To show it works for many different models let's introduce one more `JSON` payload:

```
{
  "product": {
    "products": {
      "innerArray": [
        {
          "id": "1234"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and two more `POJO` classes:

```
@JsonRootName("product")
class Product {

    private List<ProductItem> products;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = InnerListDeserializer.class)
    public List<ProductItem> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    // getters, setters, toString
}

class ProductItem {

    private String id;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Now we can test our solution:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRootName;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ContextualDeserializer;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class JSoupTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
        mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

        File jsonFile = new File("Path to 1-st JSON").getAbsoluteFile();
        File jsonFile1 = new File("Path to 2-nd JSON").getAbsoluteFile();

        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(jsonFile, Transaction.class));
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(jsonFile1, Product.class));
    }
}
```

Above example prints:

```
Transaction{items=[Item{itemNumber=193487654}, Item{itemNumber=193487654}], name='Pickle Rick'}
Product{products=[ProductItem{id='1234'}]}
```

For more info read:

1. [Custom Jackson Deserializer Getting Access to Current Field Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944086/custom-jackson-deserializer-getting-access-to-current-field-class)
2. [Getting Started with Custom Deserialization in Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization)
3. [Jackson Exceptions – Problems and Solutions](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-exception)
4. [Jackson UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE)
5. [Configuring ObjectMapper in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854030/configuring-objectmapper-in-spring)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Map` to represent the intermediate `Items` object.

Given this example (all fields `public` just for demonstration purposes):

```
public class Item {
    public String itemNumber, itemDescription, itemPrice, itemQuantity, itemBrandName, itemCategory, itemTax;
}
```

...you can achieve what you want in two ways:

### 1. By using a constructor:

```
public class TransactionDTO {
    private List<Item> items;

    @JsonCreator
    public TransactionDTO(@JsonProperty("items") final Map<String, List<Item>> items) {
        this.items = items.get("item");
    }
}
```

## 2. By using a setter:

```
public class TransactionDTO {
    private List<Item> items;

    public void setItems(final Map<String, List<Item>> items) {
        this.items = items.get("item");
    }
}
```